# Azure Media Services Encoding mp3 Failure

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I submitted a multi-hour mp3 file to the Media Services blade in the Azure Portal to generate text transcripts; upload and click [Analyze]. The job hung at 50% for about an hour, and then gave the error

```
ErrorProcessingTask       InternalError(3000)
```

I tried this multiple times, it was the same issue each time. I have found no other logged info. The first 3 times, I was using a basic instance. The 4th time I tried an S2.

Edit/Update - I have tried a new, publicly available sample file at http://traffic.libsyn.com/intellivisionaries/The_Intellivisionaries_-_Episode_04_Dec_2013.mp3 - and receive Internal Error 3000. Looking at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-index-content/#error_codes I see that this means

```
Unsupported media codec 
or
Corrupted media file 
or
No audio stream in input media.
```

So then I converted the file to Windows WAV, that gives Error Code "`ErrorParsingConfiguration`" with Error Message "`InvalidConfiguration`"

All ideas appreciated. This is a very frustrating system!

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any additional information in output asset file - JobResult.txt ? Did you tried to add job with sdk and not through portal like it described in https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-index-content/. You might get more detailed error info in error surfaced through sdk.

Comment: I tried out through azure portal and it is working for me it might be something related to audio codec or format of your file. i would suggest to contact azure support to take a look and investigate.

Comment: @GeorgeTrifonov , please try the public sample file I tried, it does not work and does not report errors. I could not find a jobresult.txt file, but according to the docs I think it would not show anything good even if I did get one.